# Limit of $n^2\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\ldots}}$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

Compute the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\ldots}}}$$

Comment: Are there $n$ radicals or infinite radicals?

Comment: @Kunnysan :$\dots$ means continued indefinitely, for anything to mean 'n' terms usage,then after $dots$ a termwill be placed to signify that is a terminating sequence.

Comment: @Simar  : the correct term is indefinite not infinite.

Comment: @Simar : There is no doubt, $\dots$ mean indefinite, do not change the question when people need to learn the meaning of well used notation,teach them what is correct.

Comment: @Arjang Why are you after that indefinate/infinite sign? Whats wrong in putting that?

Comment: @Simar : It is not mathematics! Imagine it was an English sentence that was correct to begin with then someboy kept adding something that is not needed or correct to be used, for example instead of "Jack climbed the tree" , to make sure the tree was only one tree change it to "jack climbed the a tree", it is the same with using $\infty$ when it is not meant to be there. PS: I used to do same thing too, till I learned better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:**

- For every $a\gt0$, $b=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\cdots}}}$ is such that $b^2+a=b$ and $b\gt0$, thus $b=\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+4a}$.
- When $n\to\infty$, $1-\cos(1/n)\to0$.
- When $a\to0$, $\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+4a}\to1$.
- Hence the limit you are after is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot1=+\infty$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/431634/6179) to the first point.

Comment: Sorry but you have to be MUCH more specific to describe the problems you face trying to use these hints, if you want me to be able to help you further. (The hints should be enough but...)

Comment: ((Comment by the OP now deleted.))

Comment: yup.You gave the source 3 seconds before i entered that comment.:)Any alternate method?

Comment: "Any alternate method?" What for?

Comment: Any other method you can think of except for this approach?

Comment: I did not ask "which other method" but "what motivation to look for another method".

Comment: I think that is $b^2=a+b$ instead of $b^2+b=a$, or am I leaving something out?

Comment: Same doubt ....

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Thanks for spotting this mistake. See revised version.

Answer (score 4):

Define
$$
a_m=\underbrace{\small\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\ldots+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)}}}}}_{m\text{ square roots}}
$$
$a_1=\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)}=\sqrt{2\sin^2\left(\frac1{2n}\right)}\lt2$. If $a_m\le2$, then
$$
\begin{align}
a_{m+1}
&=\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+a_m}\\
&\le\sqrt{2+2}\\[4pt]
&=2
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, note that $a_{m+1}\ge a_m$. Thus, $a_m$ is an increasing sequence, bounded above; therefore,
$$
A_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m
$$
exists, is non-negative, and is no greater than $2$. We then have
$$
A_n^2=2\sin^2\left(\frac1{2n}\right)+A_n
$$
Solving for $A_n$ yields
$$
A_n=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8\sin^2\left(\frac1{2n}\right)}}{2}
$$
$A_n\ge1$ for all $n$, therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2A_n=\infty
$$