# Is the answer 2 or 4?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

This is my first post on this forum so I apologise for not knowing how to ask this question in the desired format however I will do my best to make it clear.

First consider:
$$
 y = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{...}}}}
$$
Now, we can rewrite this as simply:
$$
y = (\sqrt{2})^y
$$
Then further rearrange this to:
$$
y^{1/y} = \sqrt{2}
$$
Thus leaving y to equal both $2$ and $4$, which obviously can't be correct. However, which is correct and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! What do you mean by ‘root2’? The square root?

Comment: Hello! Yes the square root, sorry for the confusion

Comment: But what do you mean with  the `root2` stacked?

Comment: I edited based on the second statement that $y = \sqrt{2}^y$. Is that correct ?

Comment: It's possible for an equation to have more than one solution.  If $x^2 =9$ then both $x=3$ and $x=-3$ are solutions.  This doesn't imply that $3=-3.$

Comment: No, however if it were to equal both 4 and 2, then would that not mean 4 - 2 = 0 ?

Comment: @Bernard, by the root2 stacked I mean to the power.

Comment: @goddard, but this is y = constant, so you would not expect two answers

Comment: An infinite mathematical expression is different then a regular equation. I can see two difirent possible interperetations for the expression: one the limit of $x_{n}$ when $x_{n}$ is defined recursively by $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}^{x_{n}}$ or  $x_{n+1}=x_{n}^{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @NoamKolodner The first one is correct,the second isn't because for $x_2=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ you get $x_3=(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}=2$ which is not the same as $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233290/why-cant-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-cdots2

Answer (score 2):

It converges to $2$ because for the sequence defined by $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2}^{a_n}$$
We have $a_n\leq 2$ which can easily be proved by induction if $a_n\leq 2$ then $\sqrt{2}^{a_n}=a_{n+1}\leq \sqrt{2}^2=2$.This is because $a_1\leq 2$ so once the recurrence gets near $2$ it can't get past it since $\sqrt{2}^2=2$.Formally since the sequence is bounded and increasing it is convergent.

If you had $4\geq a_1>2$ instead then the sequence would converge to $4$.

Comment: You should probably show convergence. Possibly by showing it decreases monotonously

Answer (score 1):

This is really a problem in logic.  When you solve $x^{x^{x...}}=4$ as above, you are not really finding that $x=\sqrt {2} $.  You find that **if such a value of $x $ exists, then $x=\sqrt {2} $**.  Similarly if$x^{x^{x...}}=2$ has a solution then that solution must be $x=\sqrt {2} $.  Clearly both equations cannot be satisfied by the same value of $x $, so the "fallacy" is actually an indirect proof that **at least one of them in fact has no solution.**

Having narrowed the possibilities, you now check whether  $x=\sqrt {2} $ is in fact a solution to either one by putting that value into the infinite power tower and seeing where, if anywhere, it converges.  Thus $x^{x^{x...}}=2$  has the proposed solution $x=\sqrt {2} $ leaving none for $x^{x^{x...}}=4$ .